# Give AlertDialog custom or transparent background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, android-alertdialog

I used to struggle with turning an activity's background to transparent. I would correctly set the layout background to `#00000000` and I would correctly set `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0))` in the onCreate method. However, with these two changes, I would always end up with a grayish-black container holding my layout. But then I found that I needed to edit the activity tag in the manifest to add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"`. Voila! That was all.

But now I need to turn an AlertDialog's background to transparent. There are a number of suggestions out there, and I have tried quite a few. My latest configuration is provided below. But I always end up with the same problem I used to have the activities: the grayish-black container holding my layout.  So now, my question is: how do I add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"` in the manifest file for my custom dialog?

Current code:

```
public void showMyDialog() {
  ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.CustomDialog);
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctw);
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctw.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout,
    (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.pr_root));
  builder.setView(view);
  builder.show();
}
```

Style:

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomDialog</item>
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>
```

Of course `dialog_layout` is a typical layout `.xml` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Dialog instead of `AlertDialog.Builder` and so use setContentView instead of setView.

Comment: So this kind of works. It took out the grayish-black background. But there is one problem. Now my dialog has this blue/cyan bar at the top. How do I remove that bar?

Comment: Use `builder.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

Comment: Dialogs do not play nicely with a Contextual Action Bar unfortunately, and gets misaligned. It took me a while to find that Dialog was the culprit.